# How to provide test cases for a C++ program and what if QA dept. reject it?

Tags: c++, algorithm, testing, search, sorting

This is an open-end interview question.
Given an array with 2 numbers are duplicated odd times and others duplicated even numbers, find the odd duplicated numbers.

After designing a C++ program of sorting and scan O(n lgn) , I need to provide some test cases.

What test cases do I need to provide ? 
What if QA department reject my bug fix proposal ?

thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of valid input to the function and the expected output from the function? That would define one test case.

Comment: Also, what bug fix are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all tests cases, you must test normal functionality and extreme cases.

Normal functionality:

```
Provide an array with odd duplicated numbers: result = all odd duplicated items
Provide an array with no odd duplicated numbers: no result
```

Extreme cases:

```
Provide an array with no numbers: no result
Provide an array with odd items all the same: result = array
Provide an array with even items all the same: no result
Provide an array with odd duplicated items and even duplicated items: result = odd duplicated items
```

Answer (score 2):

TioPepe has listed the required test cases, which answers the first part of your question. For the second part: If you detected a bug and fixed it, QA might reject the fix if the test haven't been extended to show what you fixed. Therefore

1.) Detect the bug

2.) Write a test which fails because of the bug.

3.) Fix the bug. The test should pass.

4.) Commit the changes.

If you omit 2.), QA should reject the change because it is not clear what you fixed.